# bsModal (ShinyBS) disabling the close button and mouse clicking close

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I am using bsModal to prompt the user information while a process is running in the background. My problem is that the user can click the close button or click the mouse cursor outside of the bsModal window to close it. Is it possible to disable the button and mouse click to prevent the user from closing the bsModal window?

I am closing the window within server.r by calling it explicity from toggleModal.

ui:

```
    bsModal("modalrun2", title = "", trigger = "proc", size = "large", HTML(paste("Calculation has started...Window will update when finished.")))
```

server:

```
            toggleModal(session, modalId = "modalrun2", toggle = "close")
```

Comment: Please post a complete example so that it is easier for others to help you.

Comment: @JJL - I had the exact same question, and received a response on SO with proper solution. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241650/8382207