# Change backdrop for a bsModal in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I am developing a Shiny app and I need to make sure the end users won't accidentally close a bsModal, because there are some action buttons on it. I've done some research and learned I need to overwrite backdrop and keyboard parameters, but even though I've seen some suggestions, I have no idea where exactly this needs to sit in my code. I am not proficient with JavaScript and very new to Shiny, so even though it feels like a simple task, I cannot get this right.

In case anyone needs it, here's a bit of dummy code that opens a modal window after a button press; I need to prevent people from closing it by accidentally clicking in the background or hitting esc.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyBS)

    ui <- fluidPage(

      sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(
            actionButton("go", "Go")
            ,bsModal("window", "Window", "go"
                    ,textOutput("print"))
          )
        ,mainPanel()
      )

    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$print = renderText("This is a test")

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to combine the solutions provided in these two threads:

[Is there a way to hide/disable the `Close` button on a `bsModal` window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241308/is-there-a-way-to-hide-disable-the-close-button-on-a-bsmodal-window/46241650#46241650)

[Prevent Bootstrap Modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152073/prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-disappearing-when-clicking-outside-or-pressing-esca)

to do something like this (in a few different combinations), but that didn't really work:

```
            actionButton("go", "Go")
            ,bsModal("window", "Window", "go"
                    ,textOutput("print")
                    ,tags$head(tags$style("#window .modal{backdrop: 'static'}")))
          )
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you try [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/modalDialog.html)

Comment: @A.Suliman Brilliant, this should serve the purpose in my case! I'm still wondering if there is a logic I could follow to achieve that through ShinyBS, as I might need to implement other tweaks to modals in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
bsModalNoClose <-function(...) {
  b = bsModal(...)
  b[[2]]$`data-backdrop` = "static"
  b[[2]]$`data-keyboard` = "false"
  return(b)
}
```

And then you can close the header and footer as well, to prevent closing there:

```
bsModalNoClose("window", "Window", "go"
               ,textOutput("print"),
               tags$head(tags$style("#window .modal-footer{display:none}
                                             .modal-header{display:none}")))
```

Comment: Awesome, really helpful! Thank you for your help Ola.

Comment: Actually I kind of stole it from someone else, but I don't remember where. I was also looking like crazy to solve the same problem :)